# Polygon does not pour all over SMA pins in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Where do I have to change settings to make my design (red) like this design on YouTube (orange).

[image: My Design]

[image: Youtube]

Comment: Not only is the polygon not connected to the 4 GND pads, it's also not connected to all the vias. It looks to me as though your footprint has a keepout rule which is preventing the polygon from pouring inside that area.

Comment: the polygon only keep out on top layer only , other layers work just fine

Comment: Did you also check the polygon net? (Properties)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check you have thermal reliefs selected.

Eg. for poured polygons:

[image]

Note that one of the selections is "none" meaning you can tell it not to pour over the pins.

Also check the polygon pour setting (and check that the net of your polygon is actually GND, of course):

[image]

---

As per @brhan's comment, if the above doesn't help there may be a keepout involved. It might be a good idea to tell us the layers involved and provide separate single-layer images, there are two slightly differenet shades of red and a dark yellow layer.

As per comment string below- try deleting the keepout from the footprint and see if that helps.

Check your polygon clearance rules too- you typically want them set to more than the absolute minimum capability to improve manufacturability.

[image]

Comment: i tried all of yours suggestion but polygn still dont work its only keep out on first layer, others layer work just fine https://imgur.com/a/wSeWZG5

Comment: You have some thermal reliefs shown there. Can you do a single layer (ctrl-S) view in 2D mode of the layer that's not connecting?

Comment: only the top layer is the problem i try rotate the component its seem like polygon wont pour under component outline https://imgur.com/a/ozCyAwO

Comment: Shift-S I meant. Fingers do it automatically.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AAE1LNZ

Comment: Okay, that's bizarre.  I wonder if the keepout violation of the vias is in some way causing an issue. I would try deleting the keepout from the footprint and see if that helps. It's not really helping.

Comment: delete keepout of footprint do the trick! thank you

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the option of selecting [thermal reliefs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_relief). That is what is disabled in your upper picture. Try searching for thermal reliefs.

Comment: i already did configure connection styles to be direct contact for pads , still polygon refuse to pour over gnd pins of SMA